# What to do when Drupal views module doesn't output what you want?

Tags: views

When a user search for a word the view should output its translation and any other vocabs that might be similar to it ( using Taxonomy terms ).

This works as the following:

The similar vocabs are actually another view that I pass ( Taxonomy ids ) to its URL as a contextual filter and it outputs all words that has the same Taxonomy term or terms. This view a lone by it self works fine when you pass Taxonomy terms manually. It doesn't produce any duplicates since I handled that by choosing 'Query settings: DISTINCT' and using aggregation.

However when I combine it with the other view and pass the Taxonomy terms using the Views UI it produce duplicates.

What should I do? Is there a way to write the view code manually or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write the view code manually or something like that?

You could easily setup a menu route and controller (or page callback in D7) to serve the same purpose. The controller would execute the query (provided by you) and return the results / page output as a renderable array.

However, there are many variables in between, so it would be hard to provide all the code.

Here is a walkthrough for D7 to starting to code your own route and callback: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

Here is one for D8:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example

It would be a good opportunity to learn how to extend Drupal and 'take control' when you don't get the result you want with Views, or, just to have more control in general.

Comment: Websmiths 404 not found

Comment: Which also is the reason why it's necessary to rephrase links or to quote at least some key lines of code provided there

Comment: Worked when I clicked on it.

Comment: Does not when clicked in the app.

Comment: Sorry... wasn't aware there is an app, I only use desktop. Changed the link to drupal.org page.

Comment: So there is a problem when I attempt to pass the data ( Vocabs ) from the controller as an array of strings to the overriding template (page.html.twig)
The following is what I return from my controller:
    $build = [
    'vocabs' => $vocabs_array
    ]
And this is the error I get "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children(). How to pass a complex 2d array to the view in this case overriding template in the theme folder?

Comment: No worries, I solved it by using a decoupled approach. The controller will output just JSON and that will be parsed using a SPA. Overriding templates still doesn't give you the necessary freedom to shape and layout your view.